# overwriting formulas in a form linked google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I have a form that submits responses to a google sheet. The form has 9 questions + sends timestamp to the sheet. I have formulas in the 11th & 12th columns, but they get overwritten to blank cells on every form submission.

Any idea how to prevent? I tried creating another sheet only for the formulas, but the cell references in those formulas just increases with every new form submission (i.e. if the cell wanted to duplicate form cell A3, when the new submission is made, the cell now says A4)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your formula as an arrayformula in row #1.

Answer (score 0):

Array formulas, "=arrayformula" applies to the column - even when the form resonse inserts a new row with the response data. It allows your formula(s) to apply to all cells in the column as opposed to being overwritten by the newly created row from the form submission.